# Delete all files older than X days

Tags: bash, shell, cron, rm

So I have a cron setup to make backups of a folder into a tarball every hour. I would like to add into the shell script that I'm using the ability to have files deleted automagically after about three days, so that I don't have a crap ton of files.

How can I go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this line to the script (modify accordingly):

```
find /path/to/backup_folder -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
```

This assumes your backup tarballs and **only** your backup tarballs reside in that folder. You could also use the `tmpwatch` utility:

```
tmpwatch -mf /path/to/backup_folder 72
```

Comment: So if I just add this in (changing the folder path), it'll delete anything older than three days?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind it is recursive. If you have any folders beneath the backup folder, add the `-maxdepth 1` switch.

Comment: If you are at all unsure, add "echo " before the rm and verify the output first.

Comment: @Chris good suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

From my `crontab` on my mac:

```
0 13 * * * /usr/bin/find /Users/dharris/.Trash -atime +14 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltd
```

Using `-atime` rather than `-mtime` means that if I *access* the file, it won't be deleted.

My version here uses `+14` for two weeks delay, change to `+3` for your needs.

Comment: +1 for atime use... I always do this too.  If I looked at the file, it may be interesting enough to keep this around a little longer.